# Pandas Dataframe returns None after recursive function?

Tags: python, pandas

I've written a simple script to save out the names of various subfolders into a spreadsheet. It seems to be doing its job at every point up to the return statement. It returns None...

If I add a print statement before the return I can see a populated dataFrame.

I guess I'm missing something obvious, would appreciate some help!
Thanks

```
import sys, os, glob
from glob import glob
import pandas as pd

def findSubFoldersMultiple(iter,data_container):
    if iter > 0:
        current_directory = sys.argv[iter]
        directory_reformatted = sys.argv[iter] + "/*/"

        folders = glob(directory_reformatted )
        folders_stripped = [ folder.replace(sys.argv[iter],'').replace('/','') for folder in folders]

        curr_data_container = pd.DataFrame({ current_directory: folders_stripped })
        combined_data_container = pd.concat([data_container,curr_data_container],axis=1)
        findSubFoldersMultiple(iter-1,combined_data_container)
    else:
        print('Populated container in loop: \n' )
        print(data_container)
        return data_container

if len(sys.argv)<2:
    print ("Please specify directory/directories.")
else:
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('subfolders.xlsx')
    empty_frame = pd.DataFrame({})
    populated_DF = findSubFoldersMultiple(len(sys.argv) - 1, empty_frame)
    print('Returned container: \n' )
    print(populated_DF)
```

Comment: Hi, could you give an example of what your sys.argv should look like ?

Comment: At the moment I'm calling it as: 
'python subfolders.py /Volumes/SSD1 /Volumes/SSD2/', for example. Will see if I can turn it into a drag and drop situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Catch the return value by changing the last line in the if block to:

```
return findSubFoldersMultiple(iter-1,combined_data_container)
```

Otherwise you're returning the value on the base case (the else block), but not returning it further up the chain of non-base case recursive calls.